# How to print the NSDate as Julian calendar formatted date in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios5, nsdate

I want to display Julian Calendar formatted dates. How can I do this using NSLog? I only got the Georgian calendar values.

Comment: A little bit of docs makes the medicine go down...

Comment: If you really want the Julian calendar, you'll have to compute it yourself, because [NSCalendar doesn't support it](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001224-SW41).  If you just want the [Julian day or Julian date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day), or the [ordinal date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_date), edit your question to say so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this formula](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/JD_Formula.php) to convert Gregorian calendar date to Julian date.