# Got nil after string to date convertation

Tags: swift, string, date, nsdateformatter

I need to convert **String** simular to "2016-07-10T21:32:20G" to **Date**.
But for some reason I've got only **nil** again and again.

I've read [an article about date formater](http://www.codingexplorer.com/swiftly-getting-human-readable-date-nsdateformatter/). And unfortunately haven't fount an answer there. I found something in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW13). And documentation tels to read about [Unicode  Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns). And it looks similar to mine.

[image]

Probably I missed something =(

My Code example. Unfortunately always get nil.

```
let lastUpdatedDateString = "2016-07-10 21:32:20"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"
let lastUpdated = dateFormatter.date(from:lastUpdatedDateString)
```

But this code works fine:

```
let lastUpdatedDateString = "2016-07-10"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
let lastUpdated = dateFormatter.date(from:lastUpdatedDateString)
```

I'm testing it in the playground.

[image]

**In fact I must convert this String("2016-07-10T21:32:20G") to Date.**

PS

Anyway, thanks for attention =)

Comment: this is the correct format: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` or `yyyy-MM-dd` without the time

Comment: WOW! yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss. It's solved the problem. May you add a bit about difference between lower and upper cases, please?

Comment: Here's the unicode format that DateFormatter uses: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: "mm" is for minutes, you used it for the part "hh:mm:ss", "MM" is for the months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I get with the playground

```
let lastUpdatedDateString = "2016-07-10T21:32:20"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddEEEEEHH:mm:ss"
let lastUpdated = dateFormatter.date(from:lastUpdatedDateString)
print(lastUpdated)
```

and it prints: `Optional(2016-07-10 19:32:20 +0000)` (I'm GMT+2)

I don't know what the G stands for so I'm not sure how I can get the last character for the pattern. `EEEEE` stands for day of the week (1 character)

EDIT: It seems `G` stand for gregorian calendar

so you can parse the last letter out of the string and add this if it's gregorian calendar (but I suppose this is the default value):

```
dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
```

If the letter's a `J` it's Julian calendar then and you can see this answer to see how to convert gregorian to julian: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12137019/2106940

Answer (score 2):

Think it's just the capitalisation in your formatter. Try this ...

```
let lastUpdatedDateString = "2016-07-10 21:32:20"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let lastUpdated = dateFormatter.date(from:lastUpdatedDateString)
```